# Monitoring MySQL's database with Socket.IO/Node.JS/Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know how I can monitore a MySQL's database with Socket.IO and Node.JS. The purpose of this is make a realtime application to send notifications for my clients. I've tried to search on the web about these questions, but without success — unfortunately.

So, can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.